# 5095 segmentation fault python3 -u

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting this error when i press a particular button in my application and it causes the application to crash.

The interesting thing is that my friend who uses windows does not face this issue AT ALL on running the same application.

This is the command that is called on pressing the button.

here self.order_list contains ids , example ["M001","M002"...]

```
def place_order(self):
        """Pop up a window to confirm the order. Displays the order list."""

        self.order_confirmation = ctk.CTkToplevel(self.root)
        self.order_confirmation.title("Order Confirmation")
        self.order_confirmation.resizable(False, False)

        if not self.order_list:

            order_confirmation_label = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.order_confirmation,
                text="No medicines selected.",
                font=self.text_font,
            )
            order_confirmation_label.pack(padx=20, pady=20, anchor=ctk.CENTER)

            close_button = ctk.CTkButton(
                self.order_confirmation,
                text="Close Window",
                command=self.order_confirmation.destroy,
            )
            close_button.pack(pady=20)

        else:

            order_confirmation_label = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.order_confirmation,
                text="The following medicines have been selected:",
                font=self.text_font,
            )
            order_confirmation_label.pack(padx=20, pady=20, anchor=ctk.CENTER)

            order_list_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.order_confirmation)

            row = 0
            total_amount = 0
            for i in self.dataset:
                if i[0] in self.order_list:

                    for j in range(0, len(i) - 1):
                        order_cell = ctk.CTkEntry(
                            order_list_frame,
                            width=self.column_widths[j],
                        )
                        try:
                            order_cell.insert(0, i[j].capitalize())
                        except AttributeError:
                            order_cell.insert(0, i[j])
                        order_cell.grid(
                            row=row,
                            column=(j + 1),
                            pady=5,
                            ipady=1,
                            padx=5,
                        )
                    row += 1
                    total_amount += i[-2]

            order_list_frame.pack(padx=20, pady=20, anchor=ctk.CENTER)

            self.final_confirmation_button = ctk.CTkButton(
                self.order_confirmation,
                text="Confirm Order",
                font=self.text_font,
                command=self.final_confirm_button_pressed,
                corner_radius=10,
                height=40,
            )

            total_amount_label = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.order_confirmation,
                text=f"Number of medicines ordered: {row}\nTotal Amount: {total_amount}",
                font=self.text_font,
            )

            total_amount_label.pack(padx=20, pady=20, anchor=ctk.CENTER)
            self.final_confirmation_button.pack(padx=20, pady=20, anchor=ctk.CENTER)
```

I tried using fault handler to find where exactly this problem lies , but it stated the cause to be root.mainloop(). I am totally blank on what to do....

I know the problem is occured on accessing some out of reach memory , but i just cant seem to crack what is it. and why is it only happening on my system (mac) and not on windows

this is what faulterror shows

```
    ("after" script)
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00000001f69cba80 (most recent call first):
  File "/Users/chiragagg5k/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1485 in mainloop
  File "/Users/chiragagg5k/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/customtkinter/windows/ctk_tk.py", line 161 in mainloop
  File "/Users/chiragagg5k/Desktop/coding_stuff/actual_coding_stuff/python_stuff/asclepius/src/asclepius/dashboard.py", line 555 in show_dashboard
  File "/Users/chiragagg5k/Desktop/coding_stuff/actual_coding_stuff/python_stuff/asclepius/src/main.py", line 18 in <module>

Extension modules: PIL._imaging, PIL._imagingtk (total: 2)
[1]    9959 segmentation fault  python3 -u
```

Comment: I can only generally recommend to scatter "print" calls over the function or to use a debugger to narrow down which call triggers the crash.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i tried running print statements in this entire code. they all ran perfectly.... now i am more confused where should i look

Comment: What does `("after" script)` refer to? Do you work with images(show_dashboard, PIL)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code that was giving the error was due to ctk.iconbitmap(). Apparently it's broken for mac and not windows

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).